# Any way to grab the HTTP request through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I have an already working application with this layout

```
<header>
<div id="frame">
<footer>
```

What I would like to do is to remove the header and footer parts of the template so that every HTTP request only transfers the `<div id="frame">`. This is the easy part.

I would then like to pick up the GET body HTTP response through AJAX and fade out the old frame and replace it with the new. **Is this possible to do?** If not, any suggestions how I can achieve this goal?

*Edit:*

Thanks for the response, guys. However, it seems that there is a misunderstanding. What I'm trying to achieve is not to load the content or remove the header and footer, I already know how to to this.

What I'm trying to achieve is to interrupt the HTTP protocol of refreshing the page on **every** request, so that if I click a working link, I would like to receive the incoming server-response directly in my javascript so I can easily replace the content of my DIV with the new 'raw' GET body of the HTTP header.

I would probably also need some sort of global link-handler to send through AJAX so that the website won't go blank when the HTTP request is first sent, but I rather focus on this later.

Comment: The application is fully working and I don't want to rewrite all of it, so there must be some way to just grab the info it sends through HTTP and use javascript to just replace the old content. Imagine binding the HTTP response to a variable through output buffering. I could then echo it into the new DIV.

Answer (score 2):

The [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) method can have a callback function as well that is executed once the fade is finished.

For loading, use the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

The first parameter allows you to extract only a page fragment.
The second one is a callback executed when the load has finished.

This gives:

```
$('#frame').fadeOut(function() {
    // the fadeOut is finished, load the content
    $(this).load('mypage.html #frame', function(response, status, xhr) {
        // the load is finished, fadeIn
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your question, this should work for you:

```
$.ajax({
    // your setup code...
    success: function(html) {
        $("HEADER, FOOTER", html).remove();
        $("containing-frame").fadeOut("fast", 
            function() {
                $(this).html(html).fadeIn("fast");
            }
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a parameter to whatever backend script you're calling via AJAX to avoid outputting the header and footer in the first place. If this isn't possible, you can use the `dataFilter` callback in `$.ajax` to modify the content however you need.

```
$.ajax('/path/to/script', {
    dataFilter: function(result, dataType) {
        // process result as necessary
        return result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simple solution would be to use `$(element).load` and it's **callback** to determine what to do when the ajax is completed.

```
$('#frame.selector').fadeOut().load('the/document.html#frame', function(data) {
  $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Note the `#frame` at the end tells jQuery to only grab what's in the element whose ID is `frame`.